# send array via onsubmit form

Tags: javascript, php

I have a html form like this :

```
<form name="form" id="form" method="get" action="www.example.com" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="window.location.href = 'www.example.com/goods:' + document.getElementsByClassName('goods').serialize;  return false;" autocomplete="off">
    <input name="goods" type="text" id="<?=$goods['id']?>" class="goods" value="" />
    <input name="goods" type="text" id="<?=$goods['id']?>" class="goods" value="" />
    <input name="goods" type="text" id="<?=$goods['id']?>" class="goods" value="" />
    <input name="goods" type="text" id="<?=$goods['id']?>" class="goods" value="" />
    <input name="goods" type="text" id="<?=$goods['id']?>" class="goods" value="" />

    <input name="submit" type="submit" class="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

I am trying to pass via onsubmit form an array with the values of the input fields and then redirect to the above url but i cant manage to do it. Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: `id` should be unique.

Comment: name="name[]" use [] this..

Answer (score 4):

To define an array in HTML forms you can use `[]`, like this:

```
<input name="goods[]"/>
```

Comment: onsubmit="window.location.href = 'www.example.com/goods:' + document.getElementsByClassName('goods').serialize;  return false;" is this correct ? or i have to change it in order to get it right

Comment: You should use `serialize` in the `form` tag. Also, `serialize` is a function from jQuery, you could simply use `$('#form').serialize()`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are trying to code like this. take name as array

```
    <form name="form" id="form" method="get" action="www.example.com" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="window.location.href = 'www.example.com/goods:' + document.getElementsByClassName('goods').serialize;  return false;" autocomplete="off">
        <?php foreach ($goods as $key => $good) { ?>
          <input name="goods[]" type="text" id="<?php echo $good['id']; ?>" class="goods" value="" />
        <?php } ?>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" class="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: onsubmit="window.location.href = 'www.example.com/goods:' + document.getElementsByClassName('goods').serialize; return false;" is this correct ? or i have to change it in order to get it right